# Unable to remove directory "obj\x64\Release\PackageUploadLayout\". Access to the path 'System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll' is denied

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, uwp

When I try to create an app package for the windows store I get

> Unable to remove directory "obj\x64\Release\PackageUploadLayout\".
>   Access to the path 'System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll' is denied.

I tried

- Clean Solution
- Removed obj\x64\Release\PackageUploadLayout folder
- Removed Read-Only Attribute from Folder
- Executed Vs 2015 as Admin
- I cloned the git repository to a complete new directory
- Restared computer

Edit:
Output:

> 2>  Computing application closure and generating interop code 2> 
>   Generating serialization code 2>  Compiling interop code 2>  Cleaning
>   up unreferenced code 2>  Generating native code 2>  Generating fixups
>   for native code 2>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(2975,5):
>   error MSB3231: Unable to remove directory
>   "obj\x64\Release\PackageUploadLayout\". Access to the path
>   'System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll' is denied.
>   2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(3513,5): error MSB6003: The specified task executable "MakeAppx.exe" could not be run. The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.

Any other ideas?

Comment: I've run into something like this.  I work around it by closing all xaml files, close Visual Studio, re-open VS and the solution, build, then create packages.  It seems like something in the designer is holding on to a dll and interfering with the build.  I do not know the real reason why.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Now I'm getting: 2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(3513,5): error MSB6003: The specified task executable "MakeAppx.exe" could not be run. The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.

Comment: That is a new one for me.  Almost seems like there is some 32/64-bit confusion.  Are you referencing any 32-bit-only libraries?  Can you create a 32-bit package?  Any custom pre- or post-build events?

Comment: I reinstalled/repaired my Visual Studio 2015. Now I can create store app packages.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem. It seems that MSIX has a problem with overwriting the ..\obj\x64\Release\PackageLayout folder.
The solution was the following... before clicking "Create App Package..." in the installer, delete the **installer** bin and obj folders. Then build the installer (the ..\obj\x64\Release\PackageLayout won't be included and so won't need to be deleted).

Note, just deleting the PackageLayout folder may not work if you are targeting more than one CPU (x86, x64)

Then click "Create App Package...". It should work.